# Use the Jacobian to find the volume element corresponding to dV=dxdydz in the transformed integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, matrix-calculus, volume

Given $x,y,z$, I calculated the $3\times3$ matrix determinant. My assignment wants it in the form

$$dx\,dy\,dz = \text{__________  }du\,dv\,dw$$

Would I just put the Jocobian into this?

$$\begin{align}
x&=u\,sin (6v)\\ y&=-6w+1\\ z&=u\,cos(6v)
\end{align}$$

Jacobian I calculated: $$-6(6u\,sin^2(6v)+6u\,cos^2(6v))$$

Comment: I would say: $-6(6u sin^2(6v)+6u cos^2(6v)) = -36u(sin^2(6v)+cos^2(6v)) = -36u \Rightarrow |J|=36u$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
   J=
  det\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   {\partial x / \partial u} & {\partial x / \partial v} & {\partial x / \partial w} \\
   {\partial y / \partial u} & {\partial y / \partial v} & {\partial y / \partial w} \\
   {\partial z / \partial u} & {\partial z / \partial v} & {\partial z / \partial w} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
= det\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   {sin(6v)} & {6ucos(6v)} & {0} \\
   {0} & {0} & {-6} \\
   {cos(6v)} & {-6usin(6v)} & {0} \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

$ J = (-6)(-1)^{2+3}det 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   {sin(6v)} & {6ucos(6v)} \\
   {cos(6v)} & {-6usin(6v)} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
= 6 (-6usin^2(6v) - 6ucos^2(6v)) = -36u$